# @media queries, Max-device-width and desktop browsers

Tags: media-queries

Has anyone had an issue with "max-device-width" and having rendering issue.
My impression was that the "max-device-width" only rendered on phones, tablets, and mobile devices, not on desktop browsers.
For me it is rendering on desktop browsers.
This happens when the browser is set and the initial load of the css file with the @Media query loads.
So if I have

@media screen and (max-width:500px), screen and (max-device-width: 1280px){/* My mobile styles here */}

the desktop browser or screen resolution of the desktop is set at 1280px, it will actually render the 1280px styles mobile styles and not the desktop styles.
Did browser makers roll "max-device-width" into their browser builds?  Any pointers or insite would be great.

EDIT:
My style sheet goes like this.

```
 /* My desktop styles here with no media query. */
 body{}
 .desktopStyle{}

 /* Then my media query for mobile devices. */
 @media screen and (max-width:500px), screen and (max-device-width: 1280px){
 /* My mobile styles here */
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not just for mobile.  You should have media queries to support desktop as well.

Comment: @Alberto. Above these styles I have the desktop styles but they are not in a media query, mainly because of older browsers, but I am guessing that because the computer's resolution is set at 1280, the max-device-width is using the computer's resolution. The 500px is so I could do some testing by resizing the desktop browser to a thin size to test mobile layout quickly. I am guessing there is an with max-device-width no only being used for "mobile" devices. I am going to try the "orientation" property to see if I can skirt around it.

Comment: Well orientation didn't work. Any other suggestions would be great. Thanks all